# Get index of random matching value

Tags: c#, list

C# provides a way to get the index of the first matching entry:

```
int first = myList.IndexOf(myList.Min())
```

and a way to get the last index:

```
int last = myList.LastIndexOf(myList.Min())
```

What's the easiest way to get a random index for a matching value, something like:

```
int anyOldOne = myList.RandomIndexOf(myList.Min())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all indexes and select a random index:

```
// Do this once only
var rnd = new Random();

// Do this each time you want a random element.
var key = myList.Min();
var indices = mylist
             .Select((n,index) => new { n, index })
             .Where(x => x.n == key)
             .Select(x => x.index)
             .ToList();
int anyOldOne= indices[rnd.Next(indices.Count)];
```

Of course this would look better in a method.

Comment: And note that you wouldn't want to call `new Random` each time you did this, in reality - see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I have created an extension method which can be used directly like you have asked in the question:-

**Extension Method:-**

```
public static int RandomIndexOf<T>(this IList<T> sequence, T element)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            List<int> matchedIndexs = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Count; i++)
            {
                if (sequence[i].Equals(element))
                    matchedIndexs.Add(i);
            }
            return matchedIndexs[rnd.Next(matchedIndexs.Count)];
        }
```

Then you can use it simply:-

```
            //Dummy Data Source
            List<int> myList = new List<int> { 4, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1 };
            int random = myList.RandomIndexOf(myList.Min());
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
int min = myList.Min();
var allIndicesWithThatValue = myList
    .Select((i, index) => new { value = i, index })
    .Where(x => x.value == min);
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomIndex = allIndicesWithThatValue
    .ElementAt(rnd.Next(allIndicesWithThatValue.Count())).index;
```

Note that you should not call this in a loop since the `Random` is seeded with the curent time. In that case you should reuse the same `Random` instance. Otherwise you will always get the same index.